# unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

In `fetchedResultsController` while setting the `NSSortDescriptor` iam getting this error **unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)**.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Alarm" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

//Below code is not working and causing error. sorting use the hours&seconds part of the time attribute  

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"time" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

                                  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
                                  NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:obj1];
                                  NSDateComponents *components2 = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:obj2];
                                  NSDate *date1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:components1];
                                  NSDate *date2 = [calendar dateFromComponents:components2];


                                  return [date1 compare:date2];

                          }];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use sort descriptors with comparator blocks everywhere - for instance not with Core Data fetches.

They work fine when you filter normal arrays, though.

Apart from that - was there a question in there that I overlooked?

Comment: What I can do for getting the above result?

Comment: @Anil Well, a simple way could be to extract all your data into an array, then sort that array with the sort descriptor from your code.

Comment: I did like that. Sorting externally after  fetching. But the problem i s am using `controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath` for updating the table view. While performing deletion some other row at indexpath is getting deleted.

Comment: I think perhaps the overlooked part is _why_ the nonsensical decision (on Apple's part) to not allow comparator blocks to work with Core Data fetches in the first place.  And also _how_ to work around it within Core Data fetches.

Answer (score 8):

As Monolo said, you can't use comparators block with Core Data.
However, you can use:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:(NSString *) ascending:(BOOL) selector:(SEL)]
```

You'll need to extend your model, if you aren't using a standard selector.

For example, I just needed to order strings "a la Finder" (i.e. 1,2,9,10, and not 1,10,2,9) and I used

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:myEntity ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
```

Take a look to the [NSSortDescriptor Class Reference by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001921-SW8)

Happy coding :)

Comment: it does not work in Core Data. The sorting happens in the  SQLite backend. localizedStandardCompare works, probably because it is a selector of NSString and apple did something to translate how it compares.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment: I started my answer with "you can't use comparators block with Core Data", I guess it's pretty obvious that it doesn't work in Core Data...

Comment: I mean the selector does not work on core data either. like if we have a `@selector(fancyCompare:)` on model. It does not work with Core Data.

Comment: I don't know about other selectors, but I can assure you @selector(localizedStandardCompare:) it does work: I'm using it in a TableViewController, applying it to a NSFetchRequest, as showed in my answer (in iOS7 and iOS8, at least).

Comment: yes, I implemented my own - (NSComparisonResult)typeCompare:(NSString*)obj2 but I get unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: typeCompare: in core data

Comment: Digging up this zombie since I found the comments unhelpful- you have to use one of the built in comparator selectors. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27972020/2200576.

Comment: +1 — was looking into blocks to fix the `[1, 10, 2]` sorting issue. `localizedStandardCompare:` works instead!

Comment: I extended the model with the @objc func localizedStandardCompare(_ string: String) -> ComparisonResultfunction but it is not called.
I found information that it should be an extension of the value type. In my case it is NSString. So I did this for an NSString with the function name `customCompare`, it was called but crashed with the error "unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: customCompare:".

So it doesn't work the same way as comparator.