# Bring certain NSFetchResults to top of list in Swift

Tags: swift, comparator, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have an iOS app with db of people's names.  I also have an array with four of these people's names (varies by user input).  I want to show a tableView with all of the entries in the db sorted by alphabet, however I want the four people in the array to appear at the top of the list using the fetch request. I do not want to manipulate the results array directly if at all possible.

Is there a way to do this with sort descriptors?  I have tried using the comparator below but had no luck.

```
var personsInArray: Array<PersonLookup>
let containsComparator: Comparator = {
                (obj1: Any!, obj2: Any!) -> ComparisonResult in
                print("comparing")
                let obj1 = obj1 as! PersonLookup
                let obj2 = obj2 as! PersonLookup
                if personsInArray.contains(obj1) && personsInArray.contains(obj2) {
                    return .orderedSame
                } else if personsInArray.contains(obj1) && !personsInArray.contains(obj2) {
                    return .orderedAscending
                } else if !personsInArray.contains(obj1) && personsInArray.contains(obj2) {
                    return .orderedDescending
                } else {
                    return .orderedSame
                }
            }
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors? = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "value", ascending: true, comparator: containsComparator), NSSortDescriptor(key: "value", ascending: true)]
```

Comment: `else { return .orderedSame }` should be at least `else { return obj1.value.compare(obj2.value)` } or something like that.

Comment: you are correct, I omitted the fact that I have a second sort descriptor that does the alphabetical sorting.

Comment: Is `fetchRequest` used with a Core Data `NSSQLiteStoreType` store?

Comment: According to this article the default behavior for Core Data is to use NSSQLiteStoreType.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/accessing_data_when_the_store_has_changed

Comment: Well the comparator approach is a non-starter since it cannot be used with Core Data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938653/unsupported-nssortdescriptor-comparator-blocks-are-not-supported